# Getting the right tint for back button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to achieve this look for my back button:

[image]

But no matter where I sample the shade of green in photoshop, it never comes out correct. For example:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can achieve the exact same look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tint color is exactly that—a tint. iOS uses that color as a base to create a nice-looking button in the style of normal navigation bars.

If you want to control your button's appearance more precisely than tinting allows, your best bet is to create a set of images and use `-setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` to use them. If you want this look for all bar button items in your app, use that method on `+[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`, rather than a specific bar button item.

Answer (score 1):

In order to produce the `BackBarButtonItem`'s gradient, iOS does the following:

1. Applies the tint color that you specify
2. Applies a transparent overlay on top of the back button

Here are the retina-display overlays it uses for iPhone (these were obtained using [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor)):

[image: Default Back Button Overlay]

Default Back Button Overlay

[image: Pressed Back Button Overlay]

Pressed Back Button Overalay

Unfortunately, **there is no way to tell iOS / UIBarButtonItem NOT to render these overlays on the back button** (thereby, this gives the default navigation bar and buttons a pretty consistent look across all apps).

If you don't want to have this overlay applied (it will darken the button in both states), you have to create your own back button images - for the `default` and `pressed` states, `portrait` and `landscape` orientations, and `retina` and `non-retina` displays (8 total images).

As [Brent Royal-Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41222) mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576330/getting-the-right-tint-for-back-button/16576558#16576558), you can apply these images using the `appearance` proxy for `UIBarButtonItem` to have them used throughout the app. In example, you'd set the default background image state like this for portrait orientation:

```
UIImage *defaultBackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My-Default-Back-Button"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:defaultBackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the button is adding another semi-transparent gray layer over the button. I can't check right now but I would look for settings to disable the semi-transparent layer effect or try different button style/states.